# Keeping the height and width of an image same in both landscape and portrait mode without using media queries

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I've a requirement where I should write an hybrid android/iOS app which is developed by `html`, `css`, `js`, `phonegap`. I'm not supposed to use my own media queries. So I'm using `bootstrap`. I've an image in header as shown in screen shot (this is in portrait mode):
[image: this is in portrait mode]
But when it is changed to landscape mode, image comes out of header as shown:
[image: landscape]
How can I keep the image same in landscape mode without using media queries?
Here is [the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/gy69L77p/2/)
**`CSS:`**

```
#headDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.home {
    margin-left: 4%;
}
.imgHeader {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner div's grow with the content right now. You have to limit that with height:100%:

```
.home {
    margin-left: 4%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also set the max-height of the image to 100%:

```
max-height: 100%;
```

I added a short JavaScript to show whats happening when the size of the header changes, just click on the home button: http://jsfiddle.net/gy69L77p/3/

Comment: I tried with `max-width: 100%`, didn't work... Thank you